# Elements of group of units of order $2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Let $U_{2^n}$ be the group of units of $\Bbb{Z}_{2^n}$, I would like to show that there are four elements in $U_{2^n}$ that satisfiy $g^2 = e$ if $n \ge 3$.  I would like to invoke this theorem

If $n \ge 3$, then $U_{2^n} = \{ \pm 5^k : 0 \le k < 2^{n -2}\}$

Obviously $\pm 1$ is two of the elements, but I'm having trouble getting the second (and showing that there are no others).  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n

Comment: Your other two elements are $\pm 5^{2^{n-3}}$. For a proof, see DonAntonio's answer. It is slightly easier to work in this product of cyclic groups. You should first answer the question: what are the $x$'s such that $2x=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$? Your case is $k$ even.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: for $\,n\ge 3\,$

$$U_{2^n}\cong C_2\times C_{2^{n-2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint for finding the roots:
$(1+4)^2=1+2\cdot4+4^2\equiv1\pmod8$, $(1+8)^2=1+2\cdot8+8^2\equiv1\pmod{16}$, $(1+16)^2=1+2\cdot16+16^2\equiv1\pmod{32}$, $\ldots$ Using that theorem you cited is a good route to proving that there are no other roots. Alternatively you can also check that
$(1+4m)^2\equiv1\pmod{2^n}$ if and only if...? But there is a slight subtlety as to how you deal with residue classes that are not congruent to $1\pmod4$. Hint: Squaring is an even function.